# Python- for each for loop iteration, append into a different list

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a for loop that is taking data and appending it into a list, but for each iteration of the for loop, I would like it to append into a different list. Is there any way to do this?

```
    value = []
    for i in list:
        value.append(i)
```

but I would like something such as

```
    for i, num in enumerate(list):
        value_i.append(num)
```

How could I go about doing this?

Comment: keep a list of lists.

Comment: lists = [list1, list2, list3]
for i, num in enumerate(list): 
    lists[i].append(num)
?

Comment: `append` implies the list already exists. Is that the case?

Comment: Yes, they already exist.

Comment: @user2631296 if they already exist, how is sza's answer correct?

Comment: Sorry? They exist in the sense that I created them, but they don't need to be preexisting. This is probably my fault for vague wording.

Comment: @user2631296 For them to *already* exist, they would have to exist *before* you begin `for i in list`. If they don't exist before that point, then using `append` would be silly – you would simply create the one-element lists at that point, as in so many of the answers. But if they do exist, then most of the below answers are wrong and would destroy the existing lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> lst = [1,2,3,4]
>>> [list(x) for x in zip(lst)]
[[1], [2], [3], [4]]
```

Btw, you should not use `list` as the variable name.

Answer (score 3):

Not lists, but close:

```
>>> zip([1, 2, 5])
[(1,), (2,), (5,)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply:

```
>>> [ [e] for e in [1, 2, 3] ]
[[1], [2], [3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you already have a collection of lists

```
my_lists = [list1, list2, list3, …, listN]
```

and a source list

```
my_sources = [val1, val2, val3, …, valN]
```

what you want is

```
for lst, src in zip(my_lists, my_sources):
    lst.append(src)
```

You could also do this by index:

```
for i in range(len(lst)):
    my_lists[i].append(my_sources[i])
```

The latter may seem less Pythonic, but it's pretty readable and probably more efficient than the `zip` approach.